# results of list comprehension and for loop not the same

Tags: python

I am trying to change characters in a string by shifting their ascii values by 2 (using `ord()`). 
This is how I did it using a for loop :

```
s='cde'
for i in s:
    i=chr(ord(i)-2)
print s
```

This simply gave me the original string -`'cde'` instead of `'abc'`. Using list comprehension however gave me the right answer :

```
str='cde'
str=''.join([chr(ord(i)-2) for i in str])
print str
```

Result : `'abc'` . Aren't both the code pieces doing the same thing? Why didn't the first one work?

Comment: No, they are not. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: that's true, but even if `s` were a list, it wouldn't have changed here..

Comment: @DSM You're right it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example

```
s='cde'
for i in s:
    i=chr(ord(i)-2)
print s
```

the variable `i` receives a *copy* of the *value* of an item of the string (read: "character"). Changing `i` does not change that string item.

Answer (score 3):

In the for loop block,

```
for i in s:
    i=chr(ord(i)-2)
```

`i` points to each and every element of the iterable object `s`. But when you assign something to `i`, it simply points to the assigned item, leaving the original item unchanged. You can confirm this with this program.

```
s='cde'
for i in s:
    print id(i)
    i=chr(ord(i)-2)
    print id(i)
print map(id, s)
```

[`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function returns the unique id of the python objects. On each iteration, it prints two ids. First one corresponds to the id of the element from the string, but second one corresponds to the assigned element.

On the other hand, list comprehension creates a new list and that is joined. Thats why the change is reflected there.

Answer (score 2):

string are immutable, but that's **not** the reason for assignment failure in a for loop, see the code below:

```
In [272]: l=list('asdf')

In [273]: l
Out[273]: ['a', 's', 'd', 'f']

In [274]: for i in l:
     ...:     i=chr(ord(i)+1)
     ...:     

In [275]: l
Out[275]: ['a', 's', 'd', 'f']
```

list object are mutable, but assignment still changes *nothing* to `l`, because `i=chr(ord(i)+1)` just make `i` refers to another string

**2. How can we change/replace values in lists in that case?**

lists are mutable, you can use `l[i]` to refer to an item in `l`, using `enumerate` allows you to get the index when iterating:

```
In [299]: for i, v in enumerate(l):
     ...:     l[i]+='z'
     ...:     

In [300]: l
Out[300]: ['az', 'sz', 'dz', 'fz']
```

**note** that althrough `l` is mutable, `l[0]` is still immutable:

```
In [301]: l=list('asdf')

In [302]: id(l[0])
Out[302]: 33639888

In [303]: for i, v in enumerate(l):
     ...:     l[i]+='z'

In [304]: l
Out[304]: ['az', 'sz', 'dz', 'fz']

In [305]: id(l[0])  #what l[0] refers to has been changed
Out[305]: 110316288
```

Comment: How can we change/replace values in lists in that case?

Comment: @VineetKaushik You shouldn't normally change the list you are iterating over - just create another list or use list comprehension if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your first does not modify the string. It can be a bit of a gotcha that the loop variable (`i` in your case) does not reference the string that it was generated from, so changing it does not reflect in the string (which is immutable). For instance:

```
s = "abc"
for index, char in enumerate(s):
    char = 'z'           #we assign tp the loop variable. the actual string is unchanged.
    print(char)          #prints 'z'
    print(s[index])      #prints the original char from the string, a -> b -> c
```

Your second example assigns directly to the string, so it is changed.

In order for your first technique to work, try this:

```
s='cde'
temp = ''
for i in s:
    temp = str.join([temp, chr(ord(i)-2)])
s = temp
```